# undefined reference to `__lzcnt16?

Tags: c, gcc, sse, undefined-reference, intrinsics

I have this code which I'm trying to run with GCC-TDM 1.7.4-2 using `-msse4.2` (I tried `msse4`) with an error:

```
sse_lzcnt.c|7|warning: implicit declaration of function '__lzcnt16'|
sse_lzcnt.c|9|warning: too many arguments for format|
obj\Debug\sse_lzcnt.o||In function `main':|
sse_lzcnt.c|7|undefined reference to `__lzcnt16'|
```

An undefined reference is usually a linking error due to a missing lib file (.a ending) but the intrinsics headers don't need one?

I made sure the intrinsics headers are in the correct include directory. Heres the code,

```
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        unsigned short __X  = 256;
        unsigned short RESULT = __lzcnt16(__X);

        printf("result: ", RESULT);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do know that this instruction is AMD-only, right ?

Comment: @Paul R I'm using an AMD-8150 FX processor so it should work. Why doesn't Intel have it?

Comment: Intel finally did add add lzcnt (starting with Haswell). But for both Intel and AMD, lzcnt is detected using a dedicated cpuid bit. What a pain. For many applications, the bsr instruction is a suitable substitute for lzcnt. Both Intel and AMD have included the bsr instruction for ages. So in many cases, it is safe to use it without any cpuid check. See this application for an example of using bsr in place of lzcnt: http://notabs.org/primitivepolynomials/version2/2.5/primitivepolynomials.htm.

Comment: @ScottD: correct me if I'm wrong but I don't think Intel has `lzcnt16` even in Haswell - it does have the 64 bit `lzcnt` though.

Comment: @Paul R, I have held off on buying a Haswell system so far, so I can't say for sure. Intel's AVX2 documentation has a surprising level of mistakes and typos, so I wouldn't bet either way without a board to test with. The latest AVX2 doc I can find (search Intel.com for 319433-014) shows all 3 forms: 16, 32, and 64 bit. The same document shows intrinsics for 32 and 64 bit only. But VS2012 and gcc 4.8.1 both handle all 3 forms.

Comment: @ScottD: I know what you mean about the Intel docs - I've been working with AVX2 the past few weeks and it's been a little frustrating. Looking at (a) the latest Intrinsics Guide (2.8.1) and the latest immintrin.h that comes with the Intel ICC 13 compiler though they both have the 32 and 64 bit lzcnt intrinsic/instruction and no mention of the 16 bit form. That does not necessarily mean that it doesn't exist though. ;-)

Comment: According to the GCC manual, http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html you need to tell it about `lzcnt` by saying `-mlzcnt`. It's a special CPUID flag to test for its presence, `CPUID.EAX=80000001H:ECX.LZCNT[bit 5]` as per Intel's manuals. Linux' `/proc/cpuinfo` flags will have it as `abm`; my test Haswell here has that feature bit set.

Comment: @PaulR `lzcnt` is simply a "prefixed `bsr`" (`0xf2` prefix). So you can use any of `0xf2 <16bit bsr>`, `0xf2 <bsr>` or `0xf2 <REX> <bsr>` to get 16/32/64bit operands. Intel just hasn't exposed the 16bit one via an intrinsic of their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the gcc command line option: -mlzcnt

Comment: And `-mlzcnt` should be where `-msse` is added for compiling right. I'm getting this now `Compiling: sse_lzcnt.c
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-mlzcnt"`

Comment: OK, sorry. For that version of gcc, use -mbmi. Apparently gcc recently changed the options that enable this instruction.

Comment: Now it doesn't even recognize it? `Compiling: sse_lzcnt.c
cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option "-mbmi"`

Comment: This is what I have `-msse2 -msse4a -msse4.2 -mbmi`.

Comment: Hello user2555139, what version of GCC-TDM are you using? I couldn't find the 1.7.4-2 you list, so I installed 4.7.1-2. With that version the following command line compiles without error:

gcc -osample.exe -msse4.2 -mlzcnt sample.c

Comment: I mixed up the 4 and 1 in the version id. Yes thats the one.

Comment: I tried doing this from the command line `

c:\>cd C:\MinGW32\bin

C:\MinGW32\bin>gcc -sse_lzcnt.exe -msse4.2 -mlzcnt sse_lzcnt.c
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-sse_lzcnt.exe'

`

Comment: And then I tried this `C:\MinGW32\bin>gcc sse_lzcnt.c -o sse_lzcnt
gcc: error: CreateProcess: No such file or directory` and I have GCC in the directory.

Comment: The first failing command, "gcc -sse_lzcnt.exe -msse4.2 -mlzcnt sse_lzcnt.c", is missing the -o before the output file name.

I am not sure why you get CreateProcess fail. It sounds like something is wrong with your gcc installation. The usual way to setup the build environment is to run the mingwvars.bat batch file. But running from the bin directory works for me, so I do not see the problem.